# How to retrieve the data from auxiliary route in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have multiple `router-outlet` in my Angular 2 project as follow:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="secondary"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="third"></router-outlet>
```

And the routing information as follow:

```
{
    path     : 'mainroute',
    component: MainComponent,
    data     : {
        mode: 'normal'
    }
},
{
    path     : 'action',
    component: SecondaryComponent,
    outlet   : 'secondary',
    data     : {
        mode: 'special'
    }
},
```

For example, if I have route `localhost:4200/mainroute(secondary:action)`, I am only able to retrieve data from main route, how can I retrieve the data from secondary `router-outlet`?

```
export class MainComponent implements {

    constructor (private route: ActivatedRoute) {

        route.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
            console.log(data); // I managed to get the data from main route here
            // how can I subscribe the data from secondary route here
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify what are you looking for. When you say " I am only able to retrieve data from main route", who's I?  Are you trying to pass data to the component in the secondary route from the parent component or you want the SecondaryComponent send the data back to the parent?

Comment: @YakovFain I have added more information. Hope it is enough. Thanks.

Comment: If you put the code (`route.data.subscribe(...)`)into `SecondaryComponent` you'll get the data of the aux route.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but how to get it from the MainComponent, I think that's what he's asking (and the answer I'm searching for too!)

Comment: You could navigate the routes, but I guess that's a bit brittle. I'd get it in the `SecondaryComponent` and then pass it along using a shared service.